# What is the correct domain for this function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

Consider the function

> $f(x)=\sin x\cdot\cos x\cdot\csc x\cdot\sec x$

Now we know that $\csc x$ is undefined ($\infty$) at $x=n\pi,n\in \mathbb Z$.Also $\sec x$ is undefined at $x=\frac {2n+1}{2}\pi,\ n\in\mathbb Z$. So the value of $f(x)$ at $x=\frac n2\pi, n\in \mathbb Z$ is undefined. So the domain of $f$ is

$$Dom\ f=\left\{x\ |\ x \in \mathbb R\ \land\ x\ne\frac{n}{2}\pi\ \text{for any }n\in \mathbb Z\right\}$$

But by simplifying the expression for $f(x)$, we get
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sin x\cdot\cos x\cdot\csc x\cdot\sec x\\
&= (\sin x\times\csc x)(\cos x\times\sec x)\\
&=(1)(1)\\
&=1
\end{align}$$
which is defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$. So by this method
$$Dom\ f=\mathbb R$$
Why is there a difference in the results of these methods and which one is the correct one?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26957/328173

Answer (score 2):

Because $\sin x \cdot \csc x = 1$ only when $\csc x$ is defined, i.e. $x \ne n\pi$.

Comment: So you mean: the first is correct or the second??

Comment: The first is correct.